# Hide UIPopoverController with double tap

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I've got splite-view application and of course there is a popover controller in the vertical DetailView, how can I hide with double-tap? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a doubleTap gesture recognizer and call `dismissPopoverAnimated:`

First declare a gesture recognizer and configure it to your view:

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer * doubleTapGesture = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapCallback:)];
 doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
 [yourView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapGesture];
 [doubleTapGesture release];
```

Then implement the callback:

```
- (IBAction) doubleTapCallback: (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    [yourPopOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]

}
```

Comment: This should do just what is needed.  But don't forget to release the doubleTapGesture after adding the recognizer to the view to prevent a memory leak